# htaccess redirect without changing url

Tags: .htaccess

I have few urls like

`http://www.mydomain.com/statecode1-folder1`

I want to redirect it to /folder1/  page but I want to show the the original urls as above in the browser address bar.

Please note that I do not have folders statecode1-folder1 and statecode2-folder1

Currently I use the below .htaccess which redirects but it changes the address bar

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/ statecode1-folder1 $  
RewriteRule   ^(.+)  / folder1 [L]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/ statecode2-folder1 $  
RewriteRule   ^(.+)  / folder1 [L]
```

Comment: you cannot do this with .htaccess

Comment: hmmm, I thought to redirect you had to specifically use the R option and that a simple rewrite was the default. Perhaps try dropping the leading slash for your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have spaces after slash! And the ending $ Maybe it is the problem? Normally, local redirect should work. Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/statecode1-folder1
RewriteRule   ^.*  /folder1 [L]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/statecode2-folder1
RewriteRule   ^.*  /folder1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is similar to this, at least you may try it:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Domain.com/statecode1-folder1 $
   RewriteRule ^(.*)  Domain.com/newpath [P]
```

for more urls use $1 sign to ensure more than one(few) url(s) with different URIs.