# htaccess load page B instead of page A without redirecting

Tags: .htaccess

Using the .htaccess file, how can I load `page B` when `page A` is loaded? I do not want the URL to change, it should still say `page A`.

example: user loads `www.mysite.com/contact` and gets the results of `www.mysite.com/contact-us`

Preferably, how can i redirect multiple URLs to the same place? Such as `.com/A`,`.com/B`, and `.com/C` all load the content of `.com/d`. Is there a way to group many of those together (as opposed to this solution: [htaccess redirect without changing url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4744336/1166285))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your URL layout I would go with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(A) [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(B) [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(C) [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(E)
RewriteRule ^.*$ /d#%1 [L]
```

Of course you can also do it in one line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(A|B|C|E) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /d#%1 [L]
```

Comment: To each his own.. LOL.. that would work too for readability however, just seems like less code using a pipe.

Comment: @Pjack yes, less code with a pipe, if he just needs to rewrite a 1 level subdir but image it not being just one or huge names it would become very confusing for a one line.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by grouping. You can match anything that comes after the domain and point it to the other URL you really want.

So for example.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /d [L]
```

That would match `www.site.com/A` or `www.site.com/B` or `www.site.com/C` and redirect to 
`www.site.com/d` without changing the URL

hope that helps.

**Edit:**

To answer your comment about specific URL's you can do this if you only want `A B or C` to redirect. Simplified example but should work fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(A|B|C)$ /d [L]
```

That would match **only** `www.site.com/A` or `www.site.com/B` or `www.site.com/C` and redirect to 
`www.site.com/d` without changing the URL.

Comment: thanks, thats almost what im looking for. Is it possible to include a list of urls that should all 'point' to the same final url? Or is it easier to just manually write them all out (if the list is going to get rather large)

Comment: is the list going to get rather large?

Comment: i'd say potentially 20, maybe more.. i'm just looking to make the .htaccess file more maintainable in the long run if it does grow alot

Comment: the `OR` aka `|` does look nice but depending on the URLS you need to redirect I would say that 1 per line would be better to maintain and read on the long term and also easy to manipulate using a script if you get to the point.

Comment: Good point... is there any way to reference the 'original url', so to forward to `/d#a`

Comment: @d-_-b I was going to update my answer to your last comment about `/d#a` but Prix already has an example you can do. :)