# prevent htaccess from loading rewritten page in new folder

Tags: .htaccess

Following up on a previous question I asked ([htaccess load page B instead of page A without redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499110/htaccess-load-page-b-instead-of-page-a-without-redirecting/17499172?noredirect=1#comment25437883_17499172)) I've run into this issue:

user goes to `.com/A` , then `.com/B` is loaded without changing the URL. this is fine.

But, the Rewrite rule also allows for a trailing slash and anything that would follow:

`RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)[\/.*] /d [L]`

The problem is, when `.com/A/` is loaded, all relative `hrefs` and links point to that 'fake' `/A/` folder.

What should I do to prevent this, and have `.com/A/` (with the trailing slash) still act as if it is part of the root directory that `.com/index.php` would use?

Thanks!

Comment: thanks @Prix, the last point was actually a typo :) . I've added the `?` but still no luck. It redirects just fine, but `/a/` is being intepreted by the server differently from `/a`

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow... I'm trying to allow an optional trailing slash, but if the slash is present, the URL should not 'act' as if it an extra directory deep

Comment: One thing to note with rewrites. I would use absolute paths or `/` in front of the path, for CSS and JS files. relative paths will mess you up every time.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't noticed that. I like to use slashes, but this code didn't have it. I guess this solves my problem :)

Comment: If you want I can make an answer. :)

Comment: There, to keep this out of the unanswered list. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note with rewrites. I would use absolute paths or `/` in front of the path, for CSS and JS files. relative paths will mess you up every time.